# Custom HTML Snippet for web components

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, web-component, code-snippets

### Summary

I'm trying to figure out how to make HTML snippet with ATTRIBUTE typeahead (intellisense) as well. We have a web component and all Tags and attributes associated to tags are documented. What is the easiest way to implement this?

### Example

We have a top level `zing-grid` tag. This tag has many attributes. For the following example I want typeahead for the `caption` attribute. The caption attribute should ONLY appear when I have a prefix of `<zing-grid`.

This issue is similar to [How to insert html attribute snippet in jsx in vscode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53020753/how-to-insert-html-attribute-snippet-in-jsx-in-vscode). In that example `div` has `class` intellisense. In this case I want the same typeahead implementation on my custom web component for the `caption` attribute.

#### Current POC snippet syntax

How do I make sure caption attribute is ONLY captured within the `zing-grid` tag

**vue.code-snippets** file

```
{
    "zing-grid": {
        "prefix": "<zing-grid",
        "body": [
            "<zing-grid \n\t$0></zing-grid>"
        ],
        "description": "ZingGrid top level tag"
    },

    "zing-grid-caption": {
        "prefix": "<zing-grid ",
        "body": [
            "<zing-grid \n\t caption=\"$1\"></zing-grid>"
        ],
        "description": "Displays a grid with the caption attribute on the grid"
    },  
    "caption": {
        "prefix": "caption",
        "body": [
            "caption=\"Hello World\""
        ],
        "description": "Displays a grid with the caption attribute on the grid"
    }

}
```

### Example Output

The following example output is from our own custom code editor implementation. We would ideally like this support for visual studio code as it is a much more powerful and complete IDE.

Cloud App Screen Recording

1. Another link since it is giving me trouble posting links https://duaw26jehqd4r.cloudfront.net/items/0E431n0Q1m261T3S1T03/Screen%20Recording%202019-02-07%20at%2003.35%20PM.mov?X-CloudApp-Visitor-Id=2965229

Comment: So... you just want us to write a VSCode extension for you?

Comment: @HereticMonkey No. I tried implementing this. I'm looking for documentation and ideas for implementation. You misread the post clearly.

I want to implement typeahead for a web component given a schema that I have already. This schema includes html tags and associated attributes and attribute values. How would I go about doing this in VSCode. code-snippets currently doesn't support this based on the given site documentation here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets

Where do I go from here?

Comment: Don't forget, misreading can occur because of an unclear text also... It's an awfully broad question in any case. I would start where I'd start any programming task: [the documentation site for the API I'm writing to](https://code.visualstudio.com/api). Try something small, then add until it works.

Answer (score 0):

### Updated

There have been new features in January 2019 documenting extended the HTML extension for users specifically for web components.
https://github.com/w3c/webcomponents/issues/776

**That should lead you to their latest release in January 2019 here:** https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_31#_html-and-css-custom-data-support

---

#### Previous Answer

Answered by @heretic-monkey. I looked up implementing VSCode extensions and not snippets. Seems the solution is there. Clearly defined in their beginning text about the capabilities. Thanks for your time.

[image]